# Competing Risk or Logit Model?

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, survival, nonlinear-regression

I have time to event data with competing events and plan to use a competing risk model for my analysis. But what are the benefits in compairson to using a logit model and adding a dummy variate that controls for competing events?